# Why are there many icons of my App?

Tags: android

When I develop my application onto my mobile phone, a lot of same icons of my application appears. So I have got icons for each Activity (sometimes twice). Not every symbol will work (the most of them shut down directly after clicking)

What's wrong?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.unitnode.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:backupAgent="com.unitnode.FileBackup"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >






    <activity
        android:name="com.unitnode.OpenProject"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="com.unitnode.Collection" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




    <activity
        android:name="com.unitnode.Property"
        android:label="@string/Settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>





      <activity
        android:name="com.unitnode.SoundRecord"
        android:label="@string/Settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.unitnode.FullscreenMode"
        android:label="@string/fullscreenMode" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity
        android:name="com.unitnode.DatenbankHelper"
        android:label="@string/Settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" 
        android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAIgcHi_mYg2z3r6ovsAyWLlVO7Zk7oKPCBxIJb-Q" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBT21LxMEdlR6cecCXb913IPo7cIP-oMiU" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
```

Comment: post the whole manifest file.. 
how many times this line <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" /> appears on your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each activity that has this intent filter gets a launcher icon:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Remove the intent filter from the activities that should not have one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
```

this line appears on your 2 activities and this cause the problem you have.
you need to write this line on the main activity that need to load when the user open the application